# {(Int)} is not identical to UInt8

Tags: swift, int, xcode6, uint

Currently using beta 5 version of swift and There must have been a change to the `+=` operator

```
func dealCards1() -> [Int] {
    for i in 0...25{
        comp1PlayDeck += shuffledDeck[i]
    }
    return comp1PlayDeck
}
```

this throws the `'[(Int)]' is not identical to 'UInt8'` I am not quite sure what changes were made however It is quite confusing.

Comment: What are the types of `comp1PlayDeck` and `shuffledDeck`?

Comment: Both are [Int] arrays

Comment: Seemed to fix it by doing this [shuffledDeck[i]]

Comment: possible duplicate of ['\[(UIView)\]' is not identical to 'UInt8' when using += in Xcode 6 beta 5. Use append method instead?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25128122/uiview-is-not-identical-to-uint8-when-using-in-xcode-6-beta-5-use-ap)

Comment: For what it's worth, if you see a change with a new beta release, it's always worth reading the release notes that are next to the new Xcode download. "The += operator on arrays only concatenates arrays, it does not append an element. This resolves ambiguity working with Any, AnyObject and related types. (17151420)"

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I suspect the error is the change in the `+=` operator, it now only combines `Array`s, not a value to an `Array`.

`shuffledDeck[i]` does not return an `Array`. Creating an array of it's value is a work-around.
Examples:

```
comp1PlayDeck += [shuffledDeck[i]]
comp1PlayDeck.append(shuffledDeck[i])
```

From the Beta5 release documents:
"• The += operator on arrays only concatenates arrays, it does not append an element. This ! resolves ambiguity working with Any, AnyObject and related types. (17151420)!"

Comment: @arcreigh I didn't assume it was you. A down vote without an explanation does not help, a reason will permit the answer to be improved.

Comment: I see I would add [shuffledDeck[i]] for other users whom don't understand what you mean by making an array of its value, I found the answer by mistake xD

Comment: Updated and added an `append` example as well.

Comment: It's a good thing shuffledDeck wasn't an array of arrays or you would have not gotten an error, but gotten unexpected behavior suddenly!

Comment: Haha indeed xD that would have been interesting

Answer (score 0):

Solved this by adding [] around array name like this

```
[shuffledDeck[i]]
```

I was still able to use the += operator